# how can I make this auto multiple line

Tags: html, css, scale, device, display

**How can I make this automatically `span` multiple lines?**

I am using HTML & CSS.

Here is my code (I changed it a bit because some parts are from PHP):

```html
<div style='border: 1px solid; padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px;'>
  <h2 style='margin: 0;'>Name&nbsp-&nbsp#id</h2>
  <hr>       
  <span>
    ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent
  </span>
</div>
<br>
```

How can I truncate these?

[image]

[image]

To this (automatically skipping a line):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding `word-wrap` and/or `overflow-wrap`

```html
<div style='border: 1px solid; padding: 10px;margin-top: 5px; max-width:200px'>
    <h2 style='margin: 0'>Name&nbsp-&nbsp#id</h2>
    <hr>
    <span style='word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;'>
        ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent</span>
</div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It work when :

```
style='word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;'
```

this code put in the div, like this

```
<div style='border: 1px solid; padding: 10px;margin-top: 5px;word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;'>
    <h2 style='margin: 0'>Name&nbsp-&nbsp#id</h2>
    <hr>
    <span>ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent</span>
</div><br>
```